# Matplotlib runtime error latex was not able to process the following string

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex

I am trying to add some text and latex to a legend and ran into some errors. I have seen multiple examples of this [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html) in the documentation but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

What am I doing wrong in my `labels` below? I have added my example that looks best and the example of my ideal label below the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)

x_values = [1,2,3,4]
y_values = [1,2,3,4]

# example that kind of works
plt.plot(x_values,y_values, 
label = r'$|askprice_a - askprice_b| >$ threshold')

plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# better example
plt.plot(x_values,y_values, 
label = r' $|\text{bid_price}_{a} - \text{bid_price}_{b}| > \text{threshold}$')

plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b' $|\\\\text{bid_price}_{a} - \\\\text{bid_price}_{b}| > \\\\text{threshold}$'
```

Comment: What errors did you run into? Please include full traceback.

Comment: I have added it, thanks  
@MuhammadMohsinKhan

Answer (score 0):

Putting the $ sign only where math notation is needed would work, for example:

```
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, label = 
         r'$|$bid price$_a$ - \textit{bid price$_b |$} $>$ \textbf{threshold}')
```

And use

```
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

instead of

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
```